# SQL Query for an entry where current date is inside start/end dates

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Using MySQL

The two fields I need to compare the current date to are: startDate, endDate

I need a query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `{$this->_sPrefix}` 
WHERE `profileID` = '{$iProfileId}' 
AND CUR_DATE() 
BETWEEN `startDate` AND `endDate` 
ORDER BY `added` DESC";
```

This is my new query but I don't know how to do both checks: profileID and the date together.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to change it.  Rather, ask your follow up in response to an answer.  I've edited my answer below to also respond to your new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that, but you have to use BETWEEN:

```
 WHERE CUR_DATE() BETWEEN `startDate` AND `endDate`
```

What SQL database are you using?

Edit (in response to edited question, and please don't keep changing the question!):

Your query looks correct, assuming that profileID, startDate, and endDate are all columns in the same table.

Also, if this is a web-facing application, please consider avoiding this kind of dynamic SQL generation as it makes your application open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

```
... WHERE CUR_DATE() BETWEEN `startDate` AND `endDate` ORDER ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...WHERE `startDate` <= CUR_DATE() and `endDate` >= CUR_DATE()
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?  It's a valid answer to the question, is it not?  Just because it doesn't look like the other answers doesn't mean it's not correct.

Comment: @Larry Lustig: I was wondering the same thing. I started to think maybe I had reversed my less than and greater than.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but it is slightly less efficient because CUR_DATE() gets evaluated twice.